# How find send_keys in selenium2library

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I work on Selenium2library with robotframework. I search an equivalent of *send_keys*() selenium function in selenium2library ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Robotframework documentation, you can use input parameters like below code.

```
Input Username
    [Arguments]    ${username}
    Input Text    username_field    ${username}

Input Password
    [Arguments]    ${password}
    Input Text    password_field    ${password}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link Selenium2Librray [Here](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html), you can find all your answers in this library.